# SonarQube MSBuild End Analysis Failure - Expected X to be a parent of Y

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am encountering the following error on the ***SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild - End Analysis*** build task in Visual Studio Team Services.

```
2017-06-12T14:35:00.1131070Z SonarQube found 7 issues out of which 1 are new
2017-06-12T14:35:00.1131070Z 
2017-06-12T14:35:00.1443593Z 
2017-06-12T14:35:00.1599853Z ##[error]System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Internal Error: expected E:\\CI02\16\s to be a parent of E:\CI02\16\s\path\to\my\file.cs ---> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Internal Error: expected E:\\CI02\16\s to be a parent of E:\CI02\16\s\path\to\my\file.cs
2017-06-12T14:35:00.1599853Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2017-06-12T14:35:00.1599853Z    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)
2017-06-12T14:35:00.1599853Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.ConstructPipelineAndDoWork(Runspace rs, Boolean performSyncInvoke)
2017-06-12T14:35:00.1599853Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeededAndDoWork(Runspace rsToUse, Boolean isSync)
2017-06-12T14:35:00.1599853Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
2017-06-12T14:35:00.1599853Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
2017-06-12T14:35:00.1599853Z    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Handlers.LegacyVSTSPowerShellHost.VSTSPowerShellHost.Main(String[] args)
2017-06-12T14:35:00.1756102Z ##[error]LegacyVSTSPowerShellHost.exe completed with return code: -1.
2017-06-12T14:35:00.1756102Z ##[section]Finishing: Complete the SonarQube analysis
```

As you can see from the logs it is failing because `E:\\CI02\16\s` is not a parent of `E:\CI02\16\s\path\to\my\file.cs` (note the different number of backslashes after `E:`).

From looking at the build task's [source code](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-vsts/blob/master/Extensions/SonarQube/Tasks/ScannerMsBuildEnd/PRCA/ReportProcessor-Module.psm1) I can see that it is expecting the the file path to start with the value of the `Build.Repository.LocalPath` task context variable. I can't see why there is a difference in the number of slashes though.

This only occurrs when the build is triggered from a pull request. If I queue the build manually it succeeds without issue.

I am using version 2.1.2 of [SonarQube for Team Services](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarqube).

Does anyone know a way around this issue or have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue resolved itself. I retriggered the build from a pull request the next morning and it succeeded without issue.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. Maybe a temporary misconfiguration of the VSTS agent.